# OpenWeatherMap not returning metric despite having included necessary parameter

Tags: http, openweathermap

I was working on some code that used the OpenWeatherMap API. I need my data to be in Celsius, so I included the necessary `&units=metric` as said on their site.

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=XXX&appid=XXX&units=metric
```

However, this returns:

```
{"error": "404"}
```

Furthermore, I tried without including the `&units=metric` parameter and everything works just fine.

So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks it is not allowed to use units parameter in this type of api call.

You need to use it in calls like this: 
[samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&units=metric&appid=xxx](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&units=metric&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22)

if you change */find* with */weather* you'll get 404 and the same if you change *q=London* with *id=524901*

So I think it's better to get the temperature in Fahrenheit and then use the formula to convert it in Celsius :

(X °F - 32) × 5/9 = Y °C